# Convert string with expression to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which has a column 'Faktor' (varchar(50)) which contains expressions like:

```
1/3
2*9/5
0.567
0.23
```

No, I am searching a way to execute a select like

```
select Faktor from Artikel
```

which should return a column of type decimal with the values

```
0.333333
3.6
0.567
0.23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with a CLR, something like this (this has the advantage of working in SET based operations whereas the dynamic sql alternatives (i.e. Abduls answer) will not):

**EDIT:** Source Code for the CLR dll (Visual Studio 2008) posted here: http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/uploaded/EvalFunction.zip

If you would prefer to compile the assembly yourself, here is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices    

Partial Public Class UserDefinedFunctions
    <Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()> _
    Public Shared Function EVAL(ByVal InputExpression As SqlString) As SqlDecimal
        Return Evaluate(InputExpression)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function Evaluate(ByVal expression As SqlString) As SqlDecimal
        Dim expressionStr As String = expression.ToString()
        Dim loDataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim loDataColumn = New DataColumn("Eval", GetType(Double), expressionStr)
        loDataTable.Columns.Add(loDataColumn)
        loDataTable.Rows.Add(0)
        Return ParseDecimal(loDataTable.Rows(0)("Eval").ToString(), 0)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ParseDecimal(ByVal InputStr As String, Optional ByVal ReturnIfFail As Decimal = 0) As Decimal
        Dim ParseOutput As Decimal = 0
        If Decimal.TryParse(InputStr, ParseOutput) = False Then
            Return ReturnIfFail
        Else
            Return ParseOutput
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

once installed and bound you could then do this:

```
SELECT Faktor, dbo.Eval(Faktor) as Result FROM Artikel
```

**Edit: OK, i have just tested this and it works fine in set-based operations etc, installation was as follows:**

```
-- Enable the CLR to run user-defined functions
EXEC sp_configure 
    'clr enabled' ,
    '1'
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

-- Set the appropriate database security permission
ALTER DATABASE [TargetDatabase] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

-- Import the assembly
CREATE ASSEMBLY EvalFunction
FROM 'C:\bin\EvalFunction.dll'  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
GO

-- Create the Eval function for easy use
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Eval
    (
      @Expression NVARCHAR(255)
    )
RETURNS DECIMAL(18, 2)
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
    EvalFunction.[EvalFunction.UserDefinedFunctions].EVAL 
GO
```

Comment: Many thanks for your sample. I have done all your steps successfully. But when I try to execute the SQL-Select, I get the fallowing Exception:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Die Datei oder Assembly "pp.sqlserver.library, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Der angegebene Assemblyname oder die Codebasis ist ungültig. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131047)
System.IO.FileLoadException

Comment: My German isnt great but it sounds like the assembly cant be found? are you sure you installed it the the correct database?

Comment: Yes - I have used your query - I have added 'use [PPSystem_DOS]' at the beginning. The Assembly is listed in the correct database when I look with Management Studio. I ask me, why it does not show the Version-Information in the Exception (instead of 0.0.0.0) - my assembly has a version.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what happens if you use my pre-compiled DLL and install it as EvalFunction.[EvalFunction.UserDefinedFunctions].EVAL instead of PPSystem_DOS - does that give the same error?

Answer (score 2):

too bad.
In the expression all numbers are `int` datatype. So, its difficult to calculate and show the result in `decimal`.

Here is a sample, hope it will help-

```
declare @expr nvarchar(10)
set @expr='2*9/5'
declare @query varchar(800)

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT CAST(@expr as decimal(5,2))
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @query='SELECT CAST('+@expr+'.0 as decimal(5,2))'
    EXECUTE(@query)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the execute statment to compile the string to the result of the represented expression or you evaluate the expression in your application.

Comment: Can you give me a sample how to do this?