# Evaluate logical expressions in string column SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table containing columns **id**(int), **logical expression**(varchar) and **result**(bit).  The logical expression is stored in a varchar which I need to evaluate and put the result into the **result** column.  For example, the column could contain:

```
'1=1'
'2<3 AND 1^1=1'
'3>4 OR 4<2'
```

The result column should then contain

```
1
0
0
```

Currently I am using a cursor to navigate the rows and using dynamic sql to evaluate the expression.

```
"IF(" + @expression + ") SET @result = 1"
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?  I would ideally like to get rid of the cursor.  Any ideas?  Would this be better performed using an assembly?

Comment: There is no efficient way to do this.  Ideally you would return the result set to an application and have that evaluate all the expressions.

Comment: If these expressions where supplied by users, then you need to beware of latent injection attacks.  Having either client code or CLR evalutate the expression would solve this problem as well.

Comment: Statements are safe so no need to worry about injections.  That are part of a back end system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a CLR.

I posted a very similar answer here: [Convert string with expression to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277884/convert-string-with-expression-to-decimal/10278603#10278603)

infact, the above answer would work fine unmodified for (and any other simple expressions):

```
SELECT dbo.eval('1=1' )
SELECT dbo.eval('3>4 OR 4<2' )
```

However, it would fail for the one using the `^` (caret) operator - you would need to tweak the CLR to handle the bitwise XOR.

Comment: No probs, Although to re-iterate my answer, you're going to struggle with expressions containing an XOR operator, SQLs notation is very different from .net and i doubt you'll find an eval that would support it. You might have to tweak the CLR to go back to SQL if the expression contains a caret (i.e. using EXEC() – this might seem pointless, but at least by wrapping it up in the CLR you can keep to set-based selects etc.

Comment: I have control over the not operator so I might just change it so that it will work with the eval.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I wrote a user-defined function in SQL to give the decimal result of evaluating infix arithmetic expressions like 1+2+3+4/(5-2). The code is [here](http://users.drew.edu/skass/sql/Infix.sql.txt). You could probably adapt it to work for your boolean expressions. It uses a table of integers called Sequence0_8000, which you can populate in any way you want.