# Converting arithmetic formula in a string into a values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which all entries are in form of arithmetic formulas (i.e. `1+2+3` etc).

In this table all columns are of type `varchar`. The table has many columns like this.

I want to calculate formula and insert the values into another. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is it only `+` or it involves `*, - ` etc.

Comment: it can contains any airthemetic operatores.

Comment: Check this link (*A T-SQL Function to Evaluate an Arithmetic Expression*) for a possible solution: http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=22848

Comment: thankYou codingbiz and MicSim

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. I hope this can assist you. It takes expression from t1 and put the result in t2. You won't want to make t1 the actual table as it deletes from the table, so you can copy the actual table value to a temp table

```
declare @t as table(val varchar(20))
declare @t2 as table(val varchar(20))
insert into @t values
('1+3'),
('2*3'),
('9+3*2')


declare @exp varchar(20)
while(exists(select 1 from @t))
begin
    select top(1) @exp = val from @t

    insert into @t2
    exec ('select '+@exp)  

    delete top (1) from @t
end

select * from @t2
```

Result

```
val
------
4
6
15
```

You can check these links [Similar question here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1171708-338-1.aspx) and [Convert string with expression to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277884/convert-string-with-expression-to-decimal/10278603#10278603)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link -
[Convert string with expression to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277884/convert-string-with-expression-to-decimal/10278603#10278603)

After you create function DBO.EVAL , just Run :-

```
select dbo.eval(column_name) from table_name;
```

Comment: If you're thinking of posting an answer that just links to another, don't; mark this question as a duplicate of the other one instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare two table variables:

- `@tabformula` in which will be stored the formulas
- `@tabresult` in which will stored the results

There is an ID column that will be used for joining the two tables.

After filling the first table with the required formulas, you declare a cursor, and then you execute the `formula` and store the result into the `@tabresult` table.

```
declare @tabformula as table (id int identity(1,1), formula
varchar(200)) declare @tabresult as table (id int, result int)

insert into @tabformula(formula) values('1+4+6+7') ;
insert into @tabformula(formula) values('10+4+60+7'); 
insert into @tabformula(formula) values('1+4+6+70') ;
insert into @tabformula(formula) values('1+44+65+7');


declare c cursor for select ID,formula from @tabformula declare @id as
int declare @formula as varchar(200)

open c fetch c into @id,@formula while @@fetch_status=0 begin print
@formula insert into @tabresult (id,result) exec( 'select '+ @id +
','+@formula ) fetch c into @id,@formula end close c deallocate c
select T1.id,t1.formula,T2.result from @tabformula t1 inner join
@tabresult t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```