# How do I evaluate a string expression in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a string `'100+200'`, how do I evaluate it?

I want to get `300` on output.

Comment: Are you wanting to evaluate the result of a string expression?  Or are you really asking how to add 2 numbers...

Comment: Don't pass it in as a string like that. Make two args and just do: SELECT arga + @argb. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting arithmetic formula in a string into a values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981883/converting-arithmetic-formula-in-a-string-into-a-values)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While an abstract example that shows the essence of the problem is good, it can also be a good idea to include some context of what you're trying to achieve in the question. Here, for instance, the question is worded so that `SELECT 100 +200` or even `SELECT 300` seem like answers, but I doubt that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @expression VARCHAR(MAX) = '100+200'
EXEC    (N'SELECT ' + @expression)
```

If it comes from a user, make sure it's sanitized

Answer (score 1):

Seriously? How about this:

```
SELECT 100 + 200;
```