# Can We evaluate a mathematical Expression to column values obtained by replacing strings with mathematical symbols?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am making a new column which will became a mathematical expression after replacing the Days/Hours/Minutes with asterisk(*) and Plus(+).

I am using below sql code to make a mathematical expression column :

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(VAL,'days','*24   +'),'Hours','*'),'Minutes','/60') as Col from #t)
```

Example the string `('5 days 12 minutes')`will became `5 *24 + 12 /60` after replacing, Now is there any solution that I can evaluate this expression i.e will get result `120` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting arithmetic formula in a string into a values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981883/converting-arithmetic-formula-in-a-string-into-a-values)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @testString nvarchar(256);
DECLARE @replacement nvarchar(256);

SET @testString = '5 days 12 minutes';
SET @replacement = (SELECT replace(replace(replace(@testString,'days','*24   +'),'Hours','*'),'Minutes','/60'));

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(256);
SET @statement = N'SELECT ' + @replacement;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a set-based approach (usable in VIEWs and functions or directly within a query) you might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('5 days 12 minutes')
                         ,('3 days 2 hours 3 minutes');
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT m.ID
          ,m.SomeString
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SomeString,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
    FROM @mockup AS m
)
,oddNumbers AS (SELECT Nr FROM (VALUES(1),(3),(5),(7),(9),(11)) AS A(Nr))
,Params AS
(
    SELECT s.ID
          ,s.SomeString
          ,s.Casted.value('(/x[sql:column("n.Nr")])[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS TheVal
          ,s.Casted.value('(/x[sql:column("n.Nr")+1])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TheUnit
    FROM Splitted AS s
    CROSS JOIN oddNumbers AS n
    WHERE s.Casted.value('(/x[sql:column("n.Nr")])[1]','nvarchar(max)') IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT p.ID
      ,p.SomeString
      ,SUM(TheVal * CASE TheUnit WHEN 'days' THEN 24.0
                                 WHEN 'hours' THEN 1.0
                                 WHEN 'Minutes' THEN (1.0/60.0) END) AS Agg
FROM Params AS p
GROUP BY p.ID,p.SomeString;
```

Assumption: Always number-unit separated by exactly one blank

The query will split your values to get the numbers together with ther associated unit.